# Is there a way to tell an iPhone Favorite Photo from Image MetaData?

Tags: ios, iphone

***End Goal***: to be able to tell from an image on an iPhone if it is a favorite photo or not

I have an iPhone that I connect to a Windows PC. I can use Windows Explorer to navigate to the photos on the device (Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM\100APPLE). The photos seem to be grouped into folders by timestamp on the image.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to tell from the file system which photos are "favorites" (i.e. on iPhone clicked the heart; they are in the favorite album); I tried to find some resources, but all discovered is that they are not in their own folder, and that they are "tagged"; I was hoping I could see that tag (i.e. right click on a file; select properties; go to details) where there is lots of information about the photo; geo location; image details; etc... but there doesn't seem to be any obvious (I'm hoping there is a non-obvious) method of identifying what images are favorites.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through the meta data of one with a heart and one without, and no difference.
The only option I could think of (which is clunky) was to use an EXIF editor to manually tag favourites

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out a very indirect method which works.

I run the google photo app and have the option enabled to sync photo stream favorites to google as favorites.
Then read the google photos favorite folder to get the file names of the favorites.
Then when I read the iPhone pics, I correlate the files and can ID the favorites that way.

It's clunky but it works.
I suspect the favorite data is stored internally in the iPhone database, so without writing a iphone app, i fear this i the most direct way you can do it.